# Return view with a variable in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, variables, return

I'm trying to have a button to set a variable, then return the same site including the variable with the value. I've tried this, and have no idea how to do this when it does not work.

```
public function printRecords() {
    $time = request('dateBtn');
    return redirect('/admin')->with('dato', $time);
}
```

That's the `UserController`

```
<form action="/booking-date" method="get">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="dateBtn" value="<?php echo $value_key . " : " . $value_value;?>">
        {{$value_key . " : " . $value_value}}
    </button>
    <br>
</form>
```

That's my blade.php code. The buttons work and returning the correct site, but I have to get the variable in order to check what stuff I want to list. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try this `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="dateBtn">{{ $dato }}</button>`

Comment: @sta Thanks, but my problem is that I want to return with a set variable, not set the name, since it allready works.

Comment: Have you tried input of type submit instead of button type submit? Also the input will only require the value and not the duplication as content / text in order to display it

Comment: @Frnak Thanks, can you please show me an example with my variables/names and stuff?

Comment: Ahh I see, I misunderstood your question a bit - gimme a second to rethink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: Based on the actual requirement.

You have multiple options to solve this - I'll still have to do some assumptions in order to answer this:

First of all the controller - it seems that you have two cases. Either you see an unfiltered List, or a filtered list. Currently I don't see a list or anything in your code, so I assume you also provide this as data to the view?

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function printRecords(Request $request) {
    // first check if the request paramter is present
    if ($request->has('dateBtn')) {
      // here you read the current input (changed it to what the docs propose)
      $time = $request->input('dateBtn');
      $dataToDisplay = // filter your data you want to display;
    } else {
      $dataToDsiplay = // load your data without a filter;
    }
    
    return redirect('/admin')->with([
      'dataToDisplay' => $dataToDisplay,
      'time' => $time
    ]);
}
```

It might be that you do your data loading at the blade file (which would not be best practice) but you will be able to transform this to balde I hope.

Here a simple example for a button where the value is not set via variable, but just as value directly (to show how to trigger the controller).

```php
<form action="/booking-date" method="get">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="dateBtn" value="2021-07-14" />
</form>
```

Obviously the list is now missing - if you add the code to the question I can add it to the answer.

---

I guess the more easy way (if you don't want to pass multiple params) would be  to do it like this:

Pass multiple params (one for the key, one for the value to your view)

```php
public function printRecords() {
    $time = request('dateBtn');
    return redirect('/admin')->with([ 'key' => 'dato', 'value' => $time]);
}
```

Then access them individually:

```php
<form action="/booking-date" method="get">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="dateBtn" value="{{ $key . ' : ' . $value }}" />
</form>
```

Update:

```php
<form action="/booking-date" method="get">
   @if(isset($key))
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="dateBtn" value="{{ $key . ' : ' . $value }}" />
   @endif
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to check in the blade.php file if the variable is set. And if it is set, I want to store it in a variable in the blade.php file.

Comment: You have to be more clear on this - what is "store a variable in the blade.php file"? What do you mean with store? I've updated my answer and added an if, but you're question is becoming more unclear. What is your actual goal? Please specifc in your original posting

Comment: I want to return to the same site with a set variable when clicking a button. The variable should be set when clicking the button. And then I want to check if the variable is set (After clicking the button).

Comment: I again have to ask you to be more clear on this. You don't give enough details to provide an asnwer. WHERE do you want to check for existence of the variable? In your blade? In your controller? What should the controller do if the variable does not exist? Should the form exist of the value is not present? What should be the value of the button if the variable is not set? Is there a default value? As you can see there are so many open questions. Please be very precise with your question.

Comment: I'm sorry for being unclear. This is how I want the program to function. I have a list with different database records. Above the list, there is a few buttons labeled with a date. When I click one of the buttons, they return to the same page, but sort the list based on what button I pressed. for example, if I press 01.01.2021 button, it should then only show the database records with 01.01.2021 as the date, and if you click another button, it changes again. I hope this was more clear.